# Can British travellers enter France via another EU member state under the 18 December COVID restrictions?

Tags: uk, schengen, france, covid-19, uk-residents

I understand that starting 18 December 2021, travellers from the UK are [indefinitely forbidden from entering France due to the Omnicron variant](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france/entry-requirements), unless they fall under a "compelling reason" exception.

However, I have failed to find any rules concerning the non-direct entry to France by British travellers from another EU member state. Whilst the rules prohibit driving *thru* France to another member state unless the transit will take under 24 hours, what about people who were recently in the UK but wish to enter France from the EU (rather than directly from England)?

For example, suppose a British person were on holiday in Germany for several days. Would they be forbidden from entering France from Germany (should there be a border check)? If so, would this prohibition apply on the basis of their residency, or would they need to have spent a certain number of days outside of the UK before entering?

Many thanks!

Comment: That may depend on the date shown in the passport of the British traveler when they entered the Schengen Area. The goal is to prevent people from a high variant area from entering France.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, do UK people get Schengen stamps in their passports these days?

Comment: @Willeke I assume so, since 2021-01-01 the 90/180 days rule applies to them.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, British citizens should have their passport stamped on entry and exit https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/eu-brexit-passport-stamps-schengen-b1956428.html

Comment: "suppose a British person were on holiday in Germany for several days": another case of interest would be a traveler from the UK to France via short-term transit in another Schengen country such as Belgium or indeed Germany.  If the policy makers are wise, they will seek to differentiate these cases, but I suspect that they're seeking more simplicity.

Comment: @phoog **compelling reason** is the simple policy. Returning home where they were before the 18 December 2021 *could* be considered compelling to avoid getting stranded. Starting a journey from the 18th to a third country would most likely **not** be considered a compelling reason.

Comment: @MarkJohnson of course. My concern here is with the potential for abuse.  To avoid that potential, France ought to be asking people entering from other EU countries whether they've been elsewhere recently.  But, as far as I can see, they are not doing that.

Comment: @phoog Maybe the main concern of the French authorities is different than yours. The  **Initial place of origin (city/country)** is being asked in the *Certificate of international travel* form that each traveler must sign.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.